# SQL Upvote Downvote system

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am currently working on a forum where posts need to have an upvote/downvote system.

My current sql(phpmyadmin) structure is like this:

```
Table 1 (posts)
| post_id | post_title | post_score |

Table 2 (pvotes)
| pvote_id | fk_post_id | fk_user_id | pvote_score |
```

I want to somehow make post_score (in table 1), find all pvote_score (table 2) columns and add/subtract them together, where fk_post_id (table 2) is = to post_id (table 1)

This way I hope to make a voting system that only allows every user to vote once, and automatically calculate a posts post_score from the pvote_score values.

**EXAMPLE**:
user_1 upvotes post_1 inserting following into table 2:
| (pvote_id) 1 | (fk_post_id) 1 | (fk_user_id) 1 | (pvote_score) 1 |

I now want post_score (table 1) to find all entries in table 2 where:
fk_post_id is same as post_id, and thereafter add or subtract the values from pvote_score and make the sum the NEW value of post_score.

I am trying to make it work just like stackoverflows own upvote/downvote system.

**EDIT 1**:

**Question:**

I want to know how can I make the `post_score` column automatically add/subtract the values from `pvotes_score` and show the sum as its value?

Comment: are you tied to a specific RDBMS? you tagged the question both with SQL-Server and mysql

Comment: PaulF: i have been searching around a couple of forums for answers, but sql in phpmyadmin is not my strong side. I hoped someone here with better knowledge could point me in the right direction of making the post_score collumn calculate itself via phpmyadmin

Comment: Paolo: mistake on my hand, i was not entirely sure about the tags, my bad

Comment: i have added an example of what action i want to take place when a vote is submitted. Sorry for the bad explanation, this is my first time asking for help on stackoverflow

Comment: The [how to ask a good question page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may be useful.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created your database structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `post_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `posts` VALUES (NULL, 'test', 0), (NULL, 'test2', 0);

CREATE TABLE `pvotes` (
  `pvote_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_post_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pvote_score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pvote_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `pvotes` VALUES (NULL, 1, 0, 2), (NULL, 1, 0, 3), (NULL, 1, 0, -1), (NULL, 2, 0, 2);
```

This is the query that should do the trick:

```
UPDATE posts SET post_score = (SELECT SUM(pvote_score) FROM pvotes WHERE fk_post_id = post_id);
```

The result I've got is this:

> post_id | post_title | post_score
>
> 1     | test       | 4
>
> 2     | test2      | 2

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for! Thank you so very much! Is there a way to make this function automated :-) ?

Comment: The best way would be to add a PHP cronjob which would update it like every X min.

Comment: thank you very much, i will try taking a look into that, marked your answer as solution aswell i think :-) thanks again

Comment: If it’s really MySQL, you can explore https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html to run something periodically.